# LLMP server tutorial

Tags: raspbian-stretch, php, lighttpd

I have searched Google for an answer but cant find an up to date tutorial for creating a LLMP server (Lighttpd instead of Apache).

I find one follow it and think I'm getting somewhere and its a year old... and packages are gone etc... can you suggest a good place that has up to date tutorials?

anywhere I can as a repo and just `apt install LLMP`.

Comment: you will probably get a  better result if you ask at a linux related website .... the question is not related to RPi

Comment: No worries, well that's probably a better option :) thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

`lighttpd` is in the repository - although I have never used it. If you search this site for tag [lighttpd} you will find other posts.

I use [NGINX](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/web-server/nginx.md) which has an official tutorial.

Comment: I haven't played much with Apache, Lighttpd or NGINX... so why not use nginx .. thanks mate :)